# better way to convert list element into a list like this one

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.2

i think this should be very easy , but i really don't know how to write it in a better way, if you know please tell me

```
#there are some points in text files and was read into a list
s = ['3,4','4,5','6,5','7,8']
#break s element to (x,y) form every element should convert to number type
points = [] 
for pStr in s:
    ss = pStr.split(',')
    points.append([int(p) for p in ss])
print(points) #[[3, 4], [4, 5], [6, 5], [7, 8]]
```

better write it in one line please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using Python 2.x you can do the following:

```
points = [map(int, x.split(',')) for x in s]
```

If using Python 3.x you'll need to pass the result of map() to list(), as it returns an iterator:

```
points = [list(map(int, x.split(','))) for x in s]
```

In action:

```
>>> s = ['3,4','4,5','6,5','7,8']
>>> points = [map(int, x.split(',')) for x in s]
>>> print(points)
[[3, 4], [4, 5], [6, 5], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: the result was this [<map object at 0x0000000002609EB8>, <map object at 0x00000000026105C0>, <map object at 0x0000000002610DD8>, <map object at 0x0000000002611AC8>],but thanks i know what to do now

Comment: @Max Which version of Python are you using?  And have you declared a map class in your own code?

Comment: @Max `python 3.x` is not widely used, so it will be better if you specify it in your questions.

Comment: @max -- on py3k, map returns an iterator.  You could use `list(map(int,x.split(',')))` to get lists, or use a list-comp as suggested in the other solution.

Comment: @Max I have added a Python 3.x compatible answer as well

Comment: @mgilson You must have read my mind - I edited my answer to say just that

Comment: I saw, and deleted my comment as it was no longer relevant :-)

Answer (score 6):

using a list comprehension:

```
In [19]: s = ['3,4','4,5','6,5','7,8']

In [21]: [[int(y) for y in x.split(',')] for x in s]
Out[21]: [[3, 4], [4, 5], [6, 5], [7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = ['3,4','4,5','6,5','7,8']
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> [literal_eval(x) for x in s]
[(3, 4), (4, 5), (6, 5), (7, 8)]
```

If you *really need* list of lists

```
>>> [list(literal_eval(x)) for x in s]
[[3, 4], [4, 5], [6, 5], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: OP is apparently using py3k, so you'll also need a `list` in there.

Comment: @mgilson, switched to a list comprehension

Comment: probably a good idea here :-). (and I like `map` as much as anybody).  I'm still not sure if I want to upvote this or not.  It's definitely clever to use `literal_eval` here, but I don't think you gain much (it constrains the separator to be `','` for example, and I doubt it would perform better) ... Anyway, I'm glad you posted it even if I don't upvote because it made me happy to see a different way of doing it.